# Lightroom CC freezes whole PC

Tags: graphics-card, freeze, amd-radeon, amd-ryzen, adobe-lightroom

I don't know what else to try, so I decided to ask here.

Sometimes Lightroom freezes the whole PC and I have to reboot. It doesn't happen anywhere else but in Lightroom, not even with games. For a few days it didn't happen, but it came back a few mins ago: the 2 monitors lost signal, and a couple of seconds later it rebooted. Temperatures look fine after this. I checked the Event viewer and there's nothing weird apart from the Kernel-Power event (cutting off the power).

My setup is

- Ryzen 7 2700,
- 32GB RAM,
- Radeon Vega 56 8GB,
- NZXT HALE82 650w power supply
- Not overclocked.

With my old setup (same but i5 3570k + OC and 16gb DDR3) Lightroom 5.7 worked fine.

I'd blame Lightroom, but I can't be sure, because it's hard to replicate. I tried disabling GPU acceleration and it didn't happen anymore (while I was testing at least), but I turned it back on and it didn't happen either.

Any help will be more than welcome. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Does Lr use Open GL? [I don't use it so idk, but I know Ps does] Open GL is notoriously poor at sharing memory & when 'full' does nasty things like locking up the machine for a few seconds… which can cause auto-logout or even hard reboot. So… if it does, try knocking the setting back down to 'basic' or even 'off' & see if things improve.

Comment: I disabled the GPU acceleration, and the problem disappeared while I tested it, but I can't know if it wasn't enough time testing it. It's kinda slow without it so I turned it back on, and it didn't freeze either, but again, maybe if I tried it longer that day it would have happened. 

One thing: for a few days I used an EVGA 600B and everything was fine. I switched back to the NZXT and it happened again. I was blaming the PSU, but the for the following 3 days nothing happened, until today.
Thank you sir.